# Lightning Network - revocation format

Tags: lightning-network

Lightning Network uses Revocable Sequence Maturing Contracts.

The [LN Paper](https://lightning.network/lightning-network-paper.pdf) specifies that:

> If one wishes to permit revocable transactions [...] the output
> transaction construction would remain a 2-of-2 multisig:
>
> 2 Alice1 Bob1 2 OP CHECKMULTISIG

However, the current implementation uses *elliptic curve point multiplication* (not *multisig*).
I have found this information in [BOLT03 - to_local](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/03-transactions.md#to_local-output), but also [here](https://medium.com/@yyforyongyu/till-its-lightning-fast-uncover-the-lightning-network-transactions-f3180e467857).

The benefits of the current approach are:

- smaller size of the Output Script
- only one signature required to unlock (vs 2 in the original spec)

Are there any other considerations besides these two for using *elliptic curve point multiplication* instead of *multisig*?

Comment: The output referred to in your citation from the paper is the *funding transaction output*, which is still the same: https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/03-transactions.md#funding-transaction-output. The commitment transaction (RSMC) spends this output to one or more outputs.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I'm still trying to fully understand the LN Paper.
But I think it **does not** refer to the *funding transaction output*, it does not make much sense in the given context.
Either way, do we know if originally the revocation was a *multisig* and then changed to *eliptic curve point multiplication*, and why?